# What happens if hashcode calculated exceeds the INTEGER MAX LIMIT?

Tags: java, hash, integer, hashmap, hashtable

Here is the hashCode() implementation from Java HashTable Class. What if the number of elements in the hashtable is huge and the hashcode exceeds the INTEGER MAX LIMIT -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 ? I assume hashCodes will be positive integers.

```
 public synchronized int hashCode() {

    int h = 0;
    if (count == 0 || loadFactor < 0)
        return h;  // Returns zero

    loadFactor = -loadFactor;  // Mark hashCode computation in progress
    Entry[] tab = table;
    for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++)
        for (Entry e = tab[i]; e != null; e = e.next)
            h += e.key.hashCode() ^ e.value.hashCode();
    loadFactor = -loadFactor;  // Mark hashCode computation complete

    return h;
}
```

Comment: The bits higher than the limit of int type (32-bit) will be discarded.

Comment: "What if the number of elements in the hashtable is huge"? What of it - hash tables have to deal with collisions. There is no requirement nor guarantee that hash codes are unique (indeed, there can be no such guarantee)

Comment: `System.out.println("Are hashCodes always positive?".hashCode());` prints `-835520151` ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I assume hashCodes will be positive integers.

No, not necessarily. They're just integers. They can definitely be negative, and it's fine to have integer overflow while computing a hash code. An ideal hash code will be spread uniformly across the whole of its range (`int` in this case). Anything *using* a hash code definitely needs to take into account the possibility of the value being negative.

Comment: If I know that my hashCode is between a certain small range, Is there a way I can tell HashMap to create buckets only for this range? This should be more efficient that to create buckets for all 2^32 numbers

Comment: @banarun: No, but the buckets aren't picked just by looking at ranges anyway, as far as I'm aware. Unless you have concrete evidence that this is causing a problem, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: If for example, the HashMap capacity is more than(or equal to) the hashCode range, then one to one mapping from hashCode to bucket would be most efficient. But that would not be the case if HashMap bucketizes for the whole integer range

Comment: @banarun: Again, do you have evidence that this is actually causing a problem in your app? If so, I suggest you ask a new question with a complete example. (Specify whether you can change your hash algorithm, too...)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes getting an overflow on the integer may be unsuitable to your needs. I say this as sometimes. I still have yet to encounter this situation but I would like to prevent it.

I'll paste you the code I use to generate a hashcode. I usually do it by taking all vars from an object and convert them to strings and do my calculations.

```
public static int generateHashCode(String ... args)
{
    int length = 0;
    char[] cArray = null;
    if(args.length == 1) {
        length = args[0].length();
        cArray = args[0].toCharArray();
    }
    else {
        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            length += args[i].length();
        }

        cArray = new char[length];
        int incrementer = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            String str = args[i];
            for(int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
                cArray[incrementer] = str.charAt(j);
                ++incrementer;
            }
        }
    }

    int h = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < cArray.length; i++) {
        h = 31*h + cArray[i];
    }

    return h;
}
```